# Не удается преобразовать из {} в "T"

Tags: c#, generics

Начинающий в C# простите за тупость:(.
в коде есть момент:
SFUSnacks - List из обьектов Snacks

onlineCart - задаётся : `OnlineCart<Snacks> onlineCart = new OnlineCart<Snacks>()`

```
List<Snacks> SFUSnacks = new List<Snacks>();
```

```
foreach (var snacks in SFUSnacks)
{
    if (snacks.Name == filter)
    {
        onlineCart.Add(snacks);
    }
}
```

также существует типозащищённый класс т.к от требуется по т.з:

```
public class OnlineCart<T>:IEnumerable
{
    private List<T> items;
    public OnlineCart()
    {
        items = new List<T>();
    }
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    
}
```

ошибка возникает на onlineCart.Add(snacks);

---

Сам класс:

```
public class Snacks : FoodProduct // Снэк
{
    public Snacks(string name, Nutrition nut) : base(name, nut)
    {
    }   
}
```

[image: Грустный момент]

Что делать подскажите пожалуйста, задание на generic и котелок совсем не варит...
Дополняю фоткой своего кринжового:( кода для пользователя aepot.
[image: Кринжик]

Comment: Показали бы на всякий и описание `SFUSnacks` тоже. Что-то с `Nullable` тут. То ли вместо `var snaks` нужно прямо `Snaks snaks` написать, то ли вместо `T` использовать `T?`. Скорее первое правильно.

Comment: Не могу нормальным кодом вставить, с телефона пишу

Comment: Вставил код в вопрос, комменты потёр

Comment: @CrazyElf для Nullable ссылочных типов `?` это просто аннотация, она никак не влияет на код, а только на ворнинги, и не может являться причиной подобных ошибок компиляции. Автор темнит, либо неправду показывает про объявление коллекций.

Comment: @aepot Ну, я всегда оставляю небольшой процент на то, что я чего-то не понимаю )  Но похоже на то.

Comment: Не нужно помещать код фоткой, это неудобно для всех. Мало кто захочет читать код с фотки. Помещайте текстом. Не знаете как нормально отформатировать - не беда, помещайте просто код без изменений, его кто-нибудь за вас отформатирует в скором времени.